# Executing a startup script in Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, startup

I want to create a version of android OS that automatically launches a browser in full screen mode and doesn't permit user to navigate away from the browser. I want this to happen on startup.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Write a home screen application that is your browser.